# What is the difference between interaction, communication, conversation, and discussion?

Tags: meaning, differences, word-usage

I think all of these are kinds of communication. But can't think the difference between the other terms

Comment: Have you looked them up in a dictionary? That's gotta be your first place to start.

Answer (score 7):

I guess you can order these verbs (and you did already) in order of general meaning.

**Interaction** can describe any process whereby the action of one participant influences the action of another participant. These participants do not have to be human, or even animate. One could describe interaction between chemicals (although that would usually lead to a *chemical reaction*) or the interaction between the sun and the planets.

**Communication** is a specific form of interaction that involves an exchange of *information*. Again, we do not necessarily need human actors. It is fine to describe two computer programs that *communicate* with each other when they send information back and forth.

**Conversation** is a specific form of communication that *usually* involves natural language, so information is exchanged in the form of language. This *does* involve human actors, usually. In a figurative sense, we can still say that two computer systems have a conversation, but that is stretching it a bit (to say the least).

**Discussion** is a specific form of conversation where the participants not only exchange information in the form of language, but they do so with the explicit intent to convince the other participants of their opinion or at least *clarify* an opinion or point of view. So the language exchanged is often in the form of *arguments*.

Comment: I'd say that discussion does not imply convincing others, that'd be *debate*'s territory; discussion usually implies trying to gain better understanding

Comment: @Raestloz: I made an edit to include your comment. _Debate_ would go indeed one level deeper again, and would be solely about convincing the other side.